# SSL Error using custom domain with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I followed the steps detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) to use a custom domain with google app engine.

- I'm the admin of the Google Apps account
- I'm the owner of the Google App Engine account
- I've added the domain to my Google Apps account through my App Engine account
- I see my App Engine app in my Google Apps account
- I set the CNAME "test" to point to ghs.googlehosted.com
- I added the web address under my Google Apps account and it says "Your users can access my-app-id at: test.mydomain.com

Now when I go to `http://test.mydomain.com`, it redirects to `https://test.mydomain.com` and I get an SSL connection error (Unable to make a secure connection to the server.)

I called Google Apps customer support because I have a paid business account, but the customer service guy said that this falls under App Engine support and he was not trained in this issue.

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've done everything correctly, you should be able to access your site at `http://test.mydomain.com`.  It sounds from the error you're getting that you're attempting to access it at `https://test.mydomain.com` (`https` as opposed to `http`).

If you want to access your app over SSL at your custom domain, you have more setup to do, as documented here: [SSL for a Custom Domain](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl).  The steps necessary are many and subject to change; that link is the official source of current information on the matter.

**Update:** From your updated information, it sounds like you may have `secure: always` set in your `app.yaml`, or the Java-configuration equivalent of this setting.  It would be helpful if you posted your configuration file.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, but `http://test.mydomain.com` does an automatic redirect to `https://test.mydomain.com`, and that is what is causing the error.

Comment: That was absolutely correct. I had `secure: always` in `app.yaml`
Thank you so much!

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but the `secure` field is NOT set!

Answer (score 1):

Also note that it takes several minutes for Google to add a certificate on a domain you recently imported (it may require time for DNS configuration to spread). I personally didn't need to add any `secure:` configuration, it just worked after some time.